How I can create a token.json using google drive api Python
I am trying to create a token.json file to save data without having to log in every time to approve an account
This is a code that deletes 100 files at the same time. Every time I run a code, I must log in to the account for approval. All you need to do is add a save file token.json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.http import BatchHttpRequest

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

def callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception:
        print(f"An error occurred: {exception}")
    else:
        print(f"Deleted file ID: {request_id}")


def main():
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    results = service.files().list(pageSize=100, fields="nextPageToken, files(id)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        batch = service.new_batch_http_request(callback=callback)
        for item in items:
            batch.add(service.files().delete(fileId=item['id']))
        batch.execute()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


I would create a function get_credentials that you can call to get the credentials you need for building your service as follows:
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def get_credentials(*,
                    scopes: list=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
                    token_path: str='token.json',
                    credentials_path: str='credentials.json'
                    ) -> Credentials:
    """Given a path to a saved token (which may not exist) and a path to
    your credentials file, return a `Credentials` instance.
    """

    def recertify():
        """Create a new Credentials instance using InstalledAppFlow."""
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            credentials_path, scopes)
        return flow.run_local_server(port=0)

    creds = None

    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists(token_path):
        # We have a token file. Recreate the credentials"
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(token_path, scopes)
        if creds.valid:
            # We have valid credentials
            return creds

    # Either token_path does not exist or the credentials are no longer valid.
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        # The credentials have expired. Try to refresh the credentials:
        try:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        except Exception:
            # Probaly the refresh token has expired, so we must start anew
            creds = recertify()
    else:
        creds = recertify()

    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open(token_path, 'w') as token_file:
        token_file.write(creds.to_json())

    return creds


def main():
    creds = get_credentials()  # Take defaults
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    ...  # etc.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Did you look at function main in my answer? It remains unchanged from your main except for the first two lines. Just call creds = get_credentials and use the result to build your service.

This code works. Thanks
